# Rows are being excluded from SQL query when using MAX

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table A

### A

MID----Totals

1  --------- 3

5  ----------3

2  ----------2

4  ----------1

When this is run

```
SELECT * FROM A HAVING A.totals=3;
```

Gives as expected

MID----Totals

1  --------- 3

5  ----------3

But When I run
`SELECT * FROM A HAVING (A.totals=(max(A.totals));`

only gives
MID----Totals

1  --------- 3

And not the second row. I need to be able to use the max value as the numbers in the total column will change. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

use this query :

```
SELECT * FROM A HAVING  A.totals=(SELECT max(B.totals) FROM A B) ;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d63077/6)

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like this:

```
SELECT d.mid
     , d.totals
  FROM ( SELECT MAX(s.totals) AS max_totals FROM A s ) t
  JOIN A d
    ON d.totals = t.max_totals
 ORDER
    BY d.mid 
     , d.totals
```

We can return an equivalent result like this:

```
SELECT d.mid
     , d.totals
  FROM A d
 WHERE d.totals IN ( SELECT MAX(s.totals) FROM A s )
 ORDER
    BY d.mid 
     , d.totals
```

---

The query in the question could also validly return zero rows.

The behavior is due to a MySQL (non-standard) extension. Other databases would balk at that query, returning an error. We can get MySQL to exhibit similar (more standard) behavior by including ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in sql_mode, and then MySQL would throw an error 1463.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` is used with `GROUP BY` aggregates

Use `WHERE` instead

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.totals = (SELECT MAX(A.totals) FROM A)
```